# Jquery three conditions list is not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to ask you help. I have a list and it's not working:
http://www.socialthink.co/#team

this is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;

    $(".view-profile").each(function (index) {
        if (i == 1) {
            $(this).addClass('ped');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('jim');
        }
        i++;
    });

    $(".ped").click(function () {
        $('#pedro').toggle();
        $('#sylvia').hide();
        $('#jimena').hide();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".team-member").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(".sil").click(function () {
        $('#pedro').hide();
        $('#sylvia').toggle();
        $('#jimena').hide();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".team-member").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(".jim").click(function () {
        $('#pedro').hide();
        $('#sylvia').hide();
        $('#jimena').toggle();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".team-member").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to add a third condition, currently works if you have two:

```
if (i == 1) {
    $(this).addClass('ped');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('jim');
}
```

but If you add the third it stops working:
this is what I'm trying:

```
if (i == 1) {
    $(this).addClass('ped');
} else if (i == 1) {
    $(this).addClass('sil');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('jim');
}
```

Please lend me a hand, 
thanks

Comment: Do you realize your if and else if statement have the same condition?

Comment: `if (i == 1) ... else if (i == 1)` O.o  What should be the result of this construct? If `i == 1` add the classes `ped` and `sil` to `this`? -> `$(this).addClass("ped sil")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Your conditions are the same for your if/else if statement. You need to provide different conditions for each.

**2.** You do not need to set the variable i and step it with each loop as the index is provided by the jQuery.each function. (0 based index)

**Try this:**

```
    $(".view-profile").each(function (i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('ped');
        } else if (i == 1) {
            $(this).addClass('sil');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('jim');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjawfo4s/

Comment: Thank you Sean, that was the solution,